# Where do you download Button.js?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In this section, Bootstrap demos button.js compoents:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons

Anyone know where the button.js download is? I can't find a stand-alone download and it's not part of the Bootstrap dist.

Comment: Github > [bootstrapjs](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master/js)

Answer (score 1):

I found it easily on the Github repository. [link](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master/js)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cdnjs .......

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/js/umd/button.js

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11121715)

Comment: @G4M1TG , this is true in general, but in this situation the question asks only for that link. So, the answer is valid, the question is somehow off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

It is also part of the sources in this ZIP-file:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/archive/v4.0.0-alpha.2.zip